# Page with dynamic content shifting to the middle on loading only safari

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, docusaurus

I created a docusaurus based website which includes some custom react components that are loaded with dynamic import using loadable-components. When I navigate between the pages both Chrome and Firefox work as expected but on Safari, as the page is loaded it is shown starting at some where in the middle depending on how many react components I have on that page.

I did a bit of research and some point to overscroll-behavior which is not currently implemented by Safari. I am not sure if that is what is causing the problem. What can be done to make sure the docs page loads only at the top even if there is dynamic content (no ssr) on the page?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had focus() calls in the components that are causing the page to scroll down only in case of Safari.